# Balance outgoing traffic

Tags: traffic

I'm running on Debian.

I have an application that runs on `localhost` and listens for incoming connections with a port range from 10000 to 11000. I want to use a tool like a traffic balancer that runs on a specified port and balances my outgoing traffic within this port range that uses my application. If I can do it with default system tools please explain to me how I can do it. I also found a tool named [balance](http://www.inlab.de/balanceng/index.html) but I am do not know how to use it with large port range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Traffic Control tool named `tc`. It's on many linux systems.
And also read the man page (`man tc`). But it's a complex tool..

An example for shaping outgoing traffic:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/